# How to complete the "Don't Need em" quest?

Tags: forced-showdown

The quest itself is simple:

> Win a battle without picking up any health globes. Globes sent to you by companion pickups or arena completion are allowed.

But I'm having a difficult time, in the heat of the battle, avoiding accidentaly picking up the healt pickups. What's a good way to actually avoid picking up the pickups I want to avoid?

Also, what's considered "a battle"?